# Can someone please let me know where i was wrong. why am i not getting the right answer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given two strings, word and key, how can I write a method sequence_search(word, key) that returns true (else false) if the characters in key appear in the same order (but not necessarily contiguous) in word?

```
def sequence_search(word, key)
       new = key.chars
        arr = []
        i = 0
        while i < word.length
        if word[i].include?(key)
        arr >> word[i]
          end
          i+= 1
          end
            if arr.join == key  # line raising exception
            return true
          end
          return false
          end
        end
    sequence_search("arcata", "cat") #=> true
    sequence_search("c1a2t3", "cat") #=> true
    sequence_search("cta", "cat")    #=> false
    sequence_search("coat", "cat")   #=> true
```

Comment: Why did you ask the same question you asked 17 hours ago?

Comment: To say it differently, do NOT ask duplicate questions.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)"

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Enumerable#all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) which returns `true` if its block never returns `false` or `nil`:

```rb
def sequence_search(word, keys)
  idx = -1
  keys.chars.all? do |c|
    idx = word.index(c) if word.index(c) && word.index(c) > idx
  end
end

sequence_search("arcata", "cat") #=> false
sequence_search("c1a2t3", "cat") #=> true
sequence_search("cta", "cat")    #=> false
sequence_search("coat", "cat")   #=> true
```

Comment: Your results are different than the expected

Comment: The OP mentioned: `returns true (else false) if the characters in key appear in the same order (but not necessarily contiguous) in word`. This is what this method does.

Comment: `"arcata"` indexes 2,3,4 contain the word `"cat"`. Why is the output `false` ?

Comment: Because  in `arcata` , `a` appears  first and then `c`. Perhaps I did not grasp the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with regex:

```
def sequence_search(word, key)
  word =~ Regexp.new(key.chars.join('.*')) ? true : false
end

p sequence_search("arcata", "cat")
p sequence_search("c1a2t3", "cat")
p sequence_search("cta", "cat")
p sequence_search("coat", "cat")

#  true
#  true
#  false
#  true
```

Comment: While it can be done using a regular expression, doing so will run more slowly. Unanchored patterns are slow, especially when compared to code that translates easily to C.